# Multiple UDF files in xlwings

Tags: python, xlwings

I would appreciate your help with specifying several UDF files in the "UDF Modules" field in the excel spreadsheet.  If I include 2 file names separated by ";" , I get an error.

Thank you
HN

Comment: Hi there, welcome to SO :) Please check out the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) guide, and consider updating your question to make it easier for others to help solve your problem :)

Comment: To clarify,  I would like to include  several udf files for import into the excel spreadsheet and I would like to specify these files in the xlwings.conf  excel sheet that overides the default xlwings.config file

Comment: I just figured out the error and got it working. Thank you